Why do I keep getting a hasEvenNumberOfParentheses error in Laravel/Blade even though my code seems correct?
The project I am working on currently has this snippet of code:
@if (isset($scripts) && is_array($scripts))
    @foreach ($scripts as $script)
        <script src="{{ $script }}"></script>
    @endforeach
@endif

Every time I make some changes and save the file, I have to wait more than 30 seconds while I get a lot of what seems like logs, and it ends in these two errors:
PHP  66. Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler->hasEvenNumberOfParentheses($expression = '@if (isset($scripts) && is_array($scripts)') /Users/[user]/Documents/GitHub/[repo]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php:541
PHP  67. token_get_all($code = '<?php @if (isset($scripts) && is_array($scripts)') /Users/[user]/Documents/GitHub/[repo]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php:606

If I remove the above code and save the code, it reloads instantly.
Same with trying to add Blade directives like @if, @foreach, even though the number of parentheses seems correct. What can I do to fix this?

I do not use Laravel, but I've seen a couple of threads suggesting that using and instead of && has worked for them. Sounds so simple as to be wrong, but seems worth a quick test.

Your code looks right, but the rendered expression in the error appears to not see the final parenthesis. Try clearing your view cache. Also, check that you're looking at the right line of code. Did you copy and paste this anywhere else that might be missing the parenthesis?

@ChrisHaas just tried doing that, still the same issue.

@maiorano84 Clearing the view cache didn't work. And this is in the main layout file, so there's only one instance of it, so no other place that would be missing the parentheses.

The same code works for me.  I guess it has to do with the PHP version in your computer.
I have used : PHP 8.3.10 and Laravel Framework 11.20.0

What happens if you remove the space between @if and (`?

I suggest you store function calls results in variables and then use those variables inside the blade @() clauses.
For example:
@php
 $existScripts = isset($scripts) && is_array($scripts);
@endphp

@if ($existScripts)
    @foreach ($scripts as $script)
        <script src="{{ $script }}"></script>
    @endforeach
@endif


I hope it helps you.
I tried with  (8.2 and 8.3) php versions and laravel (v11.11 and v11.21)

I have wasted a lot of time and I still can't find an answer to why this change with respect to Lv10. But using this way I solve the issue.
